# Filtering array of objects by removing unwanted nested object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array that contains objects of weekdays that I want to filter by elements that contain null in "opens" or "closes" (Don't want them in my final array to exist).

```
let array = [
             [
               {"weekday":1,"opens":"09:00","closes":"11:00"}, 
               {"weekday":1,"opens":null,"closes":null}
             ],
             [
               {"weekday":2,"opens":"09:00","closes":"11:00"}, 
               {"weekday":2,"opens":"12:30","closes":"17:00"},
               {"weekday":2,"opens":"18:00","closes":"null"}
             ], ...
           ]
```

I would like to return a new created array so that I don't alter the original array.

My current solution looks like that but feels ugly

```
let newArray = [];

array.forEach( (day, index)  => {
    day = day.filter( timeblock => 
       timeblock.opens != null && timeblock.closes != null
    );
    newArray.push(day);
});
```

How can I filter nested arrays more elegant? (jsfiddle if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/2jukvsoy/1/)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newArray = array.map(day => 
    day.filter(timeblock => 
        timeblock.opens != null && timeblock.closes != null
    )
);
```